# Solr: How to update only selected field using curl or command?

Tags: shell, curl, solr, command

I have Solr document as below

```
{
    "SKU":"1905/SHIRT DRESS-0",
    "DateCreated":["2019-08-18T15:21:04.090Z"],
    "DateModified":["2020-01-17T02:31:16.803Z"],
    "Name":"TIGRESS COLLECTION - SHIRT DRESS, SIZE 0 (6-8)",
    "Price":["249.00 AUD"],
    "PriceSale":["99.50 AUD"],
    "Size":["SIZE 0 (6-8)"],
    "StockLevel":["in stock"],
    "SubCategory":["KAFTAN"],
    "IsDeleted":[0],
    "ProductAddedOn":["2020-02-14T10:38:43.047Z"],
    "_version_":1658508251550973952
}
```

I want to update only 1 field from this document.

> I want to update IsDeleted = 1 where ProductAddedOn is less than today's date
>
> How to do this?

Also, I tried to update name with below command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://10.7.0.106:8983/solr/prashant1/update?_version_:1658508177093689344&versions=true&commit=true' --data-binary ' [{ "SKU" : "1905/SHIRT DRESS-0", "Name" : "update attempt with correct existing version" }]'
```

But this command removes all other fields from the document except Name and SKU.

So I want to update only 1 field from the document and other fields should remain as it is.

Comment: Did you read the Atomic update in the Solr documentation? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/updating-parts-of-documents.html

Comment: You can't do `UPDATE ... WHERE <condition>` in Solr. You'll have to retrieve the documents and then issue an update for each id.

Comment: Agree with @MatsLindh, the conditional part wont be handled here... It has to be handled separately...

Comment: But you may be able to use the conditional function queries and achieve what you are looking for. This will not change the data in your index but can manipulate the search response.  https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/function-queries.html#if-function

Comment: For small use cases that can be useful, yes. But functions will have to be evaluated for each field listed for each document in each result set, instead of using the index - which is kind of what document search engines are useful for :-)

Comment: It evaluates one field of a document when you can specify the one field upon which you want to apply the function. For example "if(termfreq (cat,'electronics'),popularity,42)" evaluates against the field 'cat'. Besides, there are no documented performance limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Solr` supports simple atomic updates (also called partial updates) to single documents via field modifiers such as add and set.

Optimistic concurrency control is another method of atomically updating documents.

Modifiers
Solr supports several modifiers that atomically update values of a document.

`set` – set or replace a particular value, or remove the value if null is specified as the new value

Example :

```
curl http://10.224.143.172:8983/solr/knowledge_combined/update?commit=true --data-binary $'[{"id" : "1", "site_name"  : {"set":"Test new change"} }]'
```

Comment: Thank you Abhijit, But I don't want to conditional update. Can you please tell me how to update all the document with isDeleted=1 without any condition?

Comment: Retrieve all the documents where isDeleted=1. Then update the documents and push it to solr for the update.